# FFmpeg re-wrap of a TS-AAC audio transport stream file to M4A-AAC: what happens by default (no "-codec copy" etc.)?

Tags: ffmpeg

What happens if you simply do `ffmpeg -i aFile.ts aFile.m4a` as opposed to `ffmpeg -i aFile.ts -codec copy aFile.m4a`, when the TS file contains only a single stream, namely AAC, and knowing that m4a files also typically contain AAC.

Does ffmpeg - even in the absence of any filters etc. - decode the original AAC and re-encode back to AAC (with whatever default parameters ffmpeg assumes for that - not necessarily matching those of the original)?  Or does it do something else?

I tried this both with and without "-codec copy" and the results in each case were AAC but the files were significantly different in size (Original TS: 8.5 MB, ffmpeg'd without "-codec copy" 7 MB, ffmpeg'd with latter 5.1 MB.

At https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html it is stated (under "3.2 Stream copy"...

> Stream copy is a mode selected by supplying the copy parameter to the
> -codec option. It makes ffmpeg omit the decoding and encoding step for the specified stream, so it does only demuxing and muxing. It is
> useful for changing the container format or modifying container-level
> metadata.
> Implied by the inverse of that situation is that, in the absence of "-codec copy", ffmpeg *will* carry out the decoding and encoding steps.

Answer (score 0):

> Does ffmpeg - even in the absence of any filters etc. - decode the original AAC and re-encode back to AAC (with whatever default parameters ffmpeg assumes for that - not necessarily matching those of the original)?

This is correct. You can look up the default setups via

```
ffmpeg -h muxer=mp4
```

This prints out a lot of info, mostly the muxer specific output options, but right at the top it says:

```
Muxer mp4 [MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)]:
    Common extensions: mp4.
    Mime type: video/mp4.
    Default video codec: h264.
    Default audio codec: aac.
```

So, `.m4a` output file by default uses `aac` audio encoder.

Then, you can try to get the details on the `aac` encoder by

```
ffmpeg -h encoder=aac
```

This returns

```
    General capabilities: delay small
    Threading capabilities: none
    Supported sample rates: 96000 88200 64000 48000 44100 32000 24000 22050 16000 12000 11025 8000 7350
    Supported sample formats: fltp
AAC encoder AVOptions:
  -aac_coder         <int>        E...A...... Coding algorithm (from 0 to 2) (default twoloop)
     anmr            0            E...A...... ANMR method
     twoloop         1            E...A...... Two loop searching method
     fast            2            E...A...... Default fast search
  -aac_ms            <boolean>    E...A...... Force M/S stereo coding (default auto)
  -aac_is            <boolean>    E...A...... Intensity stereo coding (default true)
  -aac_pns           <boolean>    E...A...... Perceptual noise substitution (default true)
  -aac_tns           <boolean>    E...A...... Temporal noise shaping (default true)
  -aac_ltp           <boolean>    E...A...... Long term prediction (default false)
  -aac_pred          <boolean>    E...A...... AAC-Main prediction (default false)
  -aac_pce           <boolean>    E...A...... Forces the use of PCEs (default false)
```

So, the builtin AAC encoder uses the default `-b:a` / `-q:a` options to set its default bitrate/quality, and neither of which default values we don't know without deep-diving into the source.

Last but perhaps the most important, there is a [FFmpeg wiki entry on AAC encoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) if you haven't seen it already.